# identifying the distribution from the pgf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Question:

$ \sqcap (s) = \frac {1}{81} (2+s)^4 $

Answer:

$ (\frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{3}s)^4 $
Which is B(4, 1/3)

Could someone explain what happens to the 1/81 and how do you get 2/3 from the 2?

Comment: You can write $81$ as $a^b$. Obviously $b=4$. Thus $a=\sqrt[\leftroot{10}\uproot{-1}4]{81}=3$.